# Is it possible to have a mysql command as default value of a field?

Tags: mysql, default-value

I wrote a select query in the default value of a field, but the code keeps getting interpreted as being string and it get inserted as text in the field. 
Is there a way to have a default value derived from a mysql command?

Comment: could you please show your query ?

Comment: No, you can't use a select query (or any function except for `now()`) for the default value of a column.

Answer (score 0):

The value in the default field is indeed just a value, it is not interpreted. To set default values dynamically, you'd need an [insert trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) to set the default value

```
CREATE TRIGGER example BEFORE INSERT ON example_table
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.bigger := NEW.value + 1;
```

This example takes the value from another field in the inserted row.